# RoboBinding: No such property exception on firePropertyChange()

Tags: java, android, mvvm, data-binding, robobinding

I'm using RoboBinding in my project.
In some place in class ContactsActivityViewModel I call firePropertyChange('Contacts') and get an exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such property 'com.psksoft.watchphone.viewmodels.ContactsActivityViewModel.Contacts'`

But the ContactsActivityViewModel class has getContacts() and setContacts(). It looks like a ViewAlbumsPresentationModel class from the RoboBinding Album Sample.

The whole source of my ContactsActivityViewModel class is available at

http://pastebin.com/raLWt6XV

The exception occurs at line 153.
Anybody knows what is happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try with the property name all in lowercase

```
_ChangeNotify.firePropertyChange("contacts");
```